# java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to import table using Java application. The query runs perfectly with MySQL Workbench:

Here is the query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Zero\\Desktop\\Book1.csv' INTO TABLE  tbl_students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\n'
```

Now using that, I included a save path for the user to locate the file here is the code:

```
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
     FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("CSV Files", "csv");
     chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    if (chooser.showSaveDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println(path.replace("\\", "\\\\"));
        ImportTBL();

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No Selection ");}
```

for the ImportTBL() here is the code

```
private void ImportTBL(){
    String sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+path.replace("\\", "\\\\")+"' INTO TABLE tbl_students "
    + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\\n'";
    System.out.println(sql);
    try{PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Import Successful!");
        }

        else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Import Fail!");}
        }

    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+ e);
        }
}
```

Comment: Try removing local such as  `LOAD DATA INFILE` .

Comment: @RahulYadav  I'm trying to import a table why should i remove LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @TomMac MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near "LOCAL.."
In short it will be a syntax error

Comment: @ZeroSerum I'm not asking you to remove `LOAD DATA INFILE` rather I asked you to drop `local` word from that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong execute method. The exception you get states that *ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data*

Try using:

```
int affectedRows = ps.executeUpdate();

if ( affectedRows <= 0 ) System.out.println("failed!");
else System.out.println("Success :)");
```

see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are executing the load statement with executeQuery() method. It is designed for executing select statements that return a resultset, not a data manupulation statement, that does not. Use executeUpdate() method instead and check  the number of rows affected to determine if the execution was successful.

Also, there is no need to prepare this statement because it's highly unlikely that the user would run this repeatedly several times right after each other. And you code does not even try to make use of the advantages offered by prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.